# Probability of an electron being knocked free

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, scattering, x-rays

Why does an electron in the K-shell have a higher probability of being knocked free during X-ray than electrons in other shells?

Comment: Electron density is the most for K-shell.

Comment: But why does electron density determine the probability? Is there a formula to determine this?

Comment: I don't know about any formula but it makes sense intuitively. You have more chances to find an electron in smaller volume than larger one.

Comment: what do you mean by "knocked free"?

Comment: When the energi from a photon is transferred to an electron and the amount of energi is enough to completely knock free the electron from the atom.

Comment: It is not really true. Not when the photon energy is far above the absorption edge.